# Philosophy behind Oracle data block, extent, segment and tablespace

Tags: oracle

What is the philosophy behind these logical definitions in Oracle database:

1. Data Block
2. Extent
3. Segment
4. Tablespace

What is the reason that Oracle uses this way to store data on disk?

Comment: One of the reasons why it was designed that way is to provide a logical structure that could be applied to multiple physical implementations

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/logical.htm) to understand more about data blocks, etc. As to the reasons why Oracle was designed so, I guess you'd have to speak to Larry Ellison about that!

Comment: *I guess you'd have to speak to Larry Ellison about that* lol :-) Larry is not going to take up this question, probably he might have forgotten the DB architecture by now.

Comment: {grins} yes, I expect so! But questions like "Why was such-and-such a piece of software designed like it was?" should expect to get answers like "Go ask the person who designed it!" *{;-)